# Правильно ли поставлены запятые

Tags: пунктуация

Предприятием внедряется новый план, согласно которому если организация отвечает одному из критериев, то ее включают в список в качестве предприятия.

Answer (score 1):

1. Правильно ли поставлены запятые? **Да, правильно.**

*Предприятием внедряется новый план, согласно **КОТОРОМУ ЕСЛИ** организация отвечает одному из критериев, **ТО** ее включают в список в качестве предприятия.*

**Перед союзом ЕСЛИ нет запятой**, так как используется **двойной союз ЕСЛИ...ТО.** В этом случае сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) рассматривается как единое целое, перестановка придаточного невозможна.

Сравним: *Предприятием внедряется новый план, согласно которому, если организация отвечает одному из критериев, ее включают в список в качестве предприятия.* В этом случае перестановка придаточного возможна, поэтому ставится запятая перед ЕСЛИ.

2. Постановка запятой регулируется правилом Розенталя ([**Запятая на стыке двух союзов**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140)):

"При «встрече» двух подчинительных союзов (или подчинительного союза и союзного слова) запятая между ними ставится, если изъятие второй придаточной части не требует перестройки главной части (практически — если дальше не следует вторая часть двойного союза *то, так* или *но*, наличие которой требует такой перестройки), и не ставится, если дальше следует указанная вторая часть двойного союза. *За огородом следовали крестьянские избы, **КОТОРЫЕ ХОТЯ** были выстроены врассыпную и не заключены в правильные улицы, **НО** показывали довольство обитателей* (Т.)".

Примечание

Повтор слова "предприятие" (стилистическая неточность).